# Диапазон времени, условие пропускает введеное значение. В чем может быть ошибка?

Tags: python

Пользователь должен ввести время в промежуток с 08:30 до 11:00.

Но условие пропускает любое значение, как можно изменить код?

```
@dp.message_handler(state=reg.tim_s)
async def get_tim(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    answer = message.text
    try:
        if answer.strtime("%H:%M") >= "08:30" and answer.strtime("%H:%M") <= "11:00":

            await state.update_data(tim_s=answer)
        else:
            await message.answer('Введите корректное время с 08:30 до 11:00, например 09:30')

    except Exception:
        await message.answer('Введи корректную дату в формате %H:%M')
```

Comment: Ну вот у вас приведён код, который это и проверяет. Чем вас не устраивает имеющийся код? Это должно быть написано **прямо в вопросе**.

Comment: Он пропускает условие и сохраняет любое время, а мне надо чтобы не было возможности вне диапозона записывать, только с 08:30 до 11:00

Comment: Вам же сказали, что "это должно быть написано прямо в вопросе".

Comment: А вы проверьте, что выдаёт `answer.strtime`, может он там с `AM`/`PM` время выдаёт или без ведущего нуля или ещё что-то такое.

Answer (score 0):

По итогу вы сравниваете не даты, а строки из-за этого ошибка

Вот пример рабочего кода:

```py
from datetime import time, datetime


@dp.message_handler(state=reg.tim_s)
async def get_tim(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    answer = message.text
    try:
        date_time = datetime.strptime(answer, '%H:%M')
    except (TypeError, ValueError):
        await message.answer('Введи корректную дату в формате %H:%M')
        return 

    input_time = date_time.time()
    if input_time >= time(hour=8, minute=30) and input_time <= time(hour=11, minute=00):
        await state.update_data(tim_s=answer) 
    else:
        await message.answer('Введите корректное время с 08:30 до 11:00, например 09:30')
```

Основные отличия что я привожу datetime к time и вынес из `try except` код который скорее всего не упадет

---

Также спасибо за ответ от @icYFTL

Comment: еще момент, не является хорошей практикой в `except` обрабатывать `Exception` в данному случаи нам лучше обрабатывать только: `TypeError` и `ValueError`

Comment: весьма дерзко...

Comment: @icYFTL извиняюсь за копирования, просто Cи стиль переменных, `try except` и что работает с datetime, а не с time. Показалось лучше сделать отдельный отчет, а то менять ваш ответ было очень кардинально

Comment: @devnull, Вопрос был поставлен конкретно. На этот вопрос был дан конкретный ответ. В столь маленьком куске кода не считаю что есть необходимо называть переменные по `PEP8`, ровно также, как и указывать тип отлавливаемого эксепшна, поскольку, это духота :D

Answer (score -1):

Вы сравниваете строки `answer.strtime("%H:%M") >= "08:30"`
А надо сравнивать объекты времени:

```
from datetime import datetime

answer = input()
try:
    dt = datetime.strptime(answer, '%H:%M')
    fdt = datetime(hour=8, minute=30, year=dt.year, day=dt.day, month=dt.month)
    sdt = datetime(hour=11, minute=0, year=dt.year, day=dt.day, month=dt.month)

    if fdt <= dt <= sdt:
        print('ok')
    else:
        print('bad')

except Exception:
    print('error')
```

Comment: Не работает, пропускает как "ок"

Comment: @AlenChet, а что попадает на вход?

Comment: извиняюсь, но небольшой комент по коду: лучше чтобы под `try except` был только `datetime.strptime` и название переменных лучше писать более подробными